# Get number of weeks commun between two ranges or dates in Jquery or Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two ranges of dates. [2016-1-1, 2016-3-1] and [2016-2-21, 2016-10-1] and i want to get the number of weeks between those two ranges of dates useing Javascript or Jquery or any libraries.
what i mean by the number of weeks between thos two ranges if for example the first range is [2016-1-1, 2016-3-1] and the second  is [2016-2-21, 2016-10-1] so there are one week between those two ranges that one week is the week from 2016-2-21 to 2016-3-1. i mean the Common

Comment: What do you mean by a week? Any seven days one after another, or only from Monday to Sunday?

Comment: @Gothdo how many from Monday to Sunday. i mean how many weeks the number of weeks.

Comment: Searching on Google: http://forums.asp.net/t/1466131.aspx?Calculate+no+of+week+between+2+date+using+javascript

Comment: Do you want number of weeks for individual ranges, or number of weeks for the portion where those two ranges intersect?

Comment: @Ouroborus i did update my question. what i mean is the Common weeks between those two ranges.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a library, [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/), that will be a great help in doing this.

Sort the ranges by begin date. This makes it easier to detect the overlap. Then calculate the overlap and turn it into weeks.

```
var format = 'YYYY-MM-DD';

function intersectDateRanges(dates) {
  if(dates.length == 0) return null;
  if(dates.length == 1) return dates[0].slice(0);
  dates = dates.map(function(v,i,a){
    var start = moment(v[0],format).startOf('day');
    var end = moment(v[1],format).endOf('day');
    return [start,end];
  });
  dates.sort(function(a,b){
    if(a[0].isBefore(b[0])) return -1;
    if(a[0].isAfter(b[0])) return 1;
    return 0;
  });
  var range = dates[0].slice(0);
  for(var i = 1; i < dates.length; i++) {
    if(dates[i][0].isAfter(range[1])) return null;
    range[0] = dates[i][0];
    if(dates[i][1].isBefore(range[1])) {
      range[1] = dates[i][1];
    }
  }
  return range;
}
function rangeToWeeks(range){
  if(!range) return NaN;
  return moment.duration(range[1] - range[0]).asWeeks();
}

var dates = [
  ['2016-1-1','2016-3-1'],
  ['2016-2-21','2016-10-1']
];
var weeksIntersect = rangeToWeeks(intersectDateRanges(dates));
```

Comment: one more thing please the result is something like this 4.25478 how can i get just 4 if the result is 4.25478 or 2 if 2.8457 ...

Comment: Pass the results through [`Math.floor()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/floor).

Answer (score -1):

Use the `Date` object.

```
d = new Date('2016-1-1');
d1 = new Date('2016-3-1');
diffweeks = (d1-d)/(7*24*60*60*1000); //Subtraction returns milliseconds.
```

Comment: You shouldn't pass a date in format like this to the `Date` constructor, because it's not guaranteed to be parsed correctly in all browsers.